# Can I use "when" immediately after the word "situation"?

Tags: word-usage

Cambridge Dictionary gives this definition about *situation*

> a condition or combination of conditions that exist at a particular time

and gives this example

> I was in a situation **where** I didn’t have cash handy

Given situation refers to *a particular time*, can I substitute **when** for **where**, and get

> I was in a situation **when** I didn’t have cash handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. There are numerous examples of 'situation when' at Google books. But 'situation where' is more common, and using 'when' doesn't change the meaning at all, as far as I can see.